# How to get the historical block mining information

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, explorers

I am still new to ethereum. How I can get the getWork information for an old block?

as an example, how to get the block header hash pow, seedhash and target for block 1000,000?

eth_getWork retrieve such information for the current block not for an old block.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [`eth_getBlockByNumber`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getblockbynumber) give you what you want?

It gives the block hash, nonce, and difficulty (among other things). The target would be computed by dividing 2^256 by the difficulty.

Comment: Thanks smarx, No it returns the the final block hash and transaction,..etc but the header hash pow (which is the header hash without nonce and mixhash) is not included. Also, the seed hash is not included in the block header. for the difficulty , yes it is included in the returned block header.